# Llamar función externa en componente Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Necesito cargar una función de un archivo .js en el componente, para ejecutarlo en el oninit.

La función a cargar sería:

```
function rearmScrollAnimations() {
    var pageloaded = $('.image-container');
    if (!pageloaded.hasClass('is-visible')){
      initScrollAnimations();
    }else{
      console.log('Todo funciona');
    }
  }
```

Como veis ejecuta "initScrollAnimations", que está dentro de este mismo js.

Muchas gracias de antemano

EDITADO:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

EDITADO: dejo el js con las funciones:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  export function rearmScrollAnimations() {
    var pageloaded = $('.image-container');
    if (!pageloaded.hasClass('is-visible')){
      initScrollAnimations();
    }else{
      console.log('Todo funciona');
    }
  }
  /* =================================================================== */
  /* VARIABLES                                                           */
  /* =================================================================== */

  var speed = 500;
  var loaded = false;
  var fireAnimation = false;
  var scrollAnimation;



  /* =================================================================== */
  /* MENU ANIMATION                                                      */
  /* =================================================================== */
  var initMenuAnimation = function() {
    var tl = new TimelineLite({onComplete: function(){
        fireAnimation = true;
        $('.ul-menu li').css('pointerEvents', 'all');
      }});

    var elements = $('#logo--header, .ul-menu >li');

    tl.pause();

    tl.call(function(){
      $('.ul-menu li').css('pointerEvents', 'none');
    });

    tl.staggerFromTo(
      elements,
      1,
      {
        alpha: 0,
        y: -10
      },
      {
        alpha: 1,
        y: 0,
        ease: Power1.easeInOut
      },
      .1
    );
    tl.call(function() {
      elements.attr('style', '');
    });
    tl.play();
  };

  /* =================================================================== */
  // Animación h1 intro
  /* =================================================================== */
  var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 50) || 7000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
  };

  TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 4);
    } else {
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
      delta = this.period;
      this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
      this.isDeleting = false;
      this.loopNum++;
      delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      that.tick();
    }, delta);
  };

  window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('home-title');
    var text = ["Hi! I'm Adri.","Well, Adri for friends :)","I'm front-end developer.", "do u want talk about it?"];
    var period = 1000;
    new TxtType(elements[0], text, period);
  };

  // On resize
  /* =================================================================== */
  $(window).resize(function(event) {


    if ($('.single-product.selfclear').length) {
      // $productContainerGlass = $('.single-product.selfclear .left');
      // bottomLunettes = getHeightElem($productContainerGlass) + 143;
    }
    if (!isMobile()) {
      if ($('#menu-toggle').hasClass('is-open')) {
        toggleHeader();
        $('#menu-toggle').removeClass('is-open');
      }
    }

    if(!isMobile() && !scrollAnimation ) {
      initScrollAnimations();
      initParallax();
      initParallaxVertical();
    }

  });


  /* =================================================================== */
  /* SCROLL PARALLAX                                                     */
  /* =================================================================== */
  var initParallax = function() {
    // Controller
    var controllerParallax = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      // addIndicators: true,
    });


    // Reveal elements
    $('.page .i-parallax').each(function() {

      var element = $(this);
      var sceneParallax = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: this,
        reverse: true,
        duration: '200%'
      });

      // Animation
      var tl = new TimelineLite();

      tl.fromTo(
        this,
        Math.floor((Math.random() * 1.5) + 1),
        {
          y: '20',
        },
        {
          y: '-200',
          ease: Linear.easeNone
        }
      );

      sceneParallax.setTween(tl);
      sceneParallax.addTo(controllerParallax);
    });
  };



  var initParallaxVertical = function() {
    // Controller
    var controllerParallaxVertical = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      // addIndicators: true,
    });
    var tl;

    // Reveal elements
    $('.page .e-parallax').each(function() {

      var element = $(this);
      var sceneParallaxVertical = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: this.closest('.e-parallax-container'),
        reverse: true,
        duration: '200%'
      });

      // Animation
      if (element.parents('.page').hasClass('is--journal')) {
        tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.fromTo(
          this,
          1,
          {
            x: '0',
          },
          {
            x: '100',
            ease: Linear.easeNone
          }
        );
      } else {
        tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.fromTo(
          this,
          1,
          {
            x: '0',
          },
          {
            x: '-100',
            ease: Linear.easeNone
          }
        );
      }


      sceneParallaxVertical.setTween(tl);
      sceneParallaxVertical.addTo(controllerParallaxVertical);
    });
  };


  /* =================================================================== */
  /* SCROLL ANIMATION                                       */
  /* =================================================================== */

  var initScrollAnimations = function() {
    // Controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      // addIndicators: true
    });


    // Reveal elements
    $('.page .scroll-reveal').each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var isText;
      var images;
      var splitText;
      var lines;
      var intro;
      var words;
      var btn;
      var elements;
      var tl;

      var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: this,
        reverse: false
      });

      if(element.hasClass('intro')) {
        intro = element.find('.image-container');

        //Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.pause();
        tl.call(function () {
          intro.each(function () {
            var intr = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
              intr.addClass('is-visible');
            },4000);
          });
        }, null, null, 0);
        tl.play();
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);
      };
      if (element.hasClass('module-slider-gallery') ) {

        images = element.find('.slick-active');
        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.pause();

        tl.call(function() {
          images.each(function(index) {
            var image = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              image.addClass('is-visible');
            }, index*100);
          });
        }, null, null, 0);

        tl.play();
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);

      } else if(element.hasClass('part--image-transition') || element.hasClass('part--image-top-transition') ){

        if (element.hasClass('part--image-top-transition')) {
          var offset = -320;
        } else {
          var offset = -100;
        }

        if( $('p', $(this)).length ) {
          elements = element.find('p');
        }


        images = element.find('.image-container');
        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.pause();

        tl.call(function() {
          images.each(function(index) {
            var image = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              image.addClass('is-visible');
            }, index*100);
          });
        }, null, null, 0);

        tl.staggerFromTo(
          elements,
          0.5,
          {
            alpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            alpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power1.easeOut
          },
          0.15,
          0.5
        );


        if (fireAnimation) {
          tl.play();
        } else {
          var play = setInterval(function(){
            // console.log(fireAnimation);
            if (fireAnimation) {
              clearInterval(play);
              tl.play();
            }
          }, 100);
        }
        scene.offset(offset);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);

      } else if(element.hasClass('is--title')){
        if( $('h1', $(this)).length ) {
          isText = true;
          splitText = new SplitText(
            element.find('h1'),
            {
              type: 'lines,words',
              linesClass: 'split-line',
              wordsClass: 'split-word'
            }
          );
          lines = element.find('.split-line');
          words = element.find('.split-word');
        } else {
          isText = false;
        }

        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.pause();

        if(!!isText) {
          lines.each(function(index) {
            var line = $(this);

            tl.fromTo(
              line.find('.split-word'),
              0.5,
              {
                alpha: 0,
                top: -line.height()
              },
              {
                alpha: 1,
                top: -4,
                ease: Power3.easeOut
              },
              0+(index*0.1)
            );
          });
        }
        tl.call(function() {
          // splitText.revert();
        });
        if (fireAnimation) {
          tl.play();
        } else {
          var play = setInterval(function(){
            // console.log(fireAnimation);
            if (fireAnimation) {
              clearInterval(play);
              tl.play();
            }
          }, 100);
        }
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);

      } else if(element.hasClass('bloc') && element.hasClass('scroll-reveal--first')){
        // console.log('part bloc');

        if( $('h1', $(this)).length || $('h2', $(this)).length || $('p', $(this)).length ) {
          isText = true;
          splitText = new SplitText(
            element.find('h1, h2, p'),
            {
              type: 'lines,words',
              linesClass: 'split-line',
              wordsClass: 'split-word'
            }
          );
          lines = element.find('.split-line');
          words = element.find('.split-word');
        } else {
          isText = false;
        }

        images = element.find('.image-container');
        btn = element.find('.is--cta-anim');

        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.pause();

        tl.call(function() {
          images.each(function(index) {
            var image = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              image.addClass('is-visible');
            }, index*100);
          });
        }, null, null, 0);

        if(!!isText) {
          lines.each(function(index) {
            var line = $(this);

            tl.fromTo(
              line.find('.split-word'),
              0.5,
              {
                alpha: 0,
                top: -line.height()
              },
              {
                alpha: 1,
                top: -4,
                ease: Power3.easeOut
              },
              0.5+(index*0.1)
            );
          });
        }
        tl.fromTo(
          btn,
          0.5,
          {
            alpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            alpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power3.easeOut
          },
          0.5+(lines.length*0.1)
        );
        tl.call(function() {
          // splitText.revert();
        });
        if (fireAnimation) {
          tl.play();
        } else {
          var play = setInterval(function(){
            // console.log(fireAnimation);
            if (fireAnimation) {
              clearInterval(play);
              tl.play();
            }
          }, 100);
        }
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);


      } else if(element.hasClass('landing-row')){
        if( $('h1', $(this)).length || $('h2', $(this)).length || $('p', $(this)).length ) {
          isText = true;
          splitText = new SplitText(
            element.find('h1, h2, p'),
            {
              type: 'lines,words',
              linesClass: 'split-line',
              wordsClass: 'split-word'
            }
          );
          lines = element.find('.split-line');
          words = element.find('.split-word');
        } else {
          isText = false;
        }

        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.pause();

        if(!!isText) {
          lines.each(function(index) {
            var line = $(this);

            tl.fromTo(
              line.find('.split-word'),
              0.5,
              {
                alpha: 0,
                top: -line.height()
              },
              {
                alpha: 1,
                top: -4,
                ease: Power3.easeOut
              },
              0.5+(index*0.1)
            );
          });
        }
        tl.call(function() {
          // splitText.revert();
        });
        tl.play();
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);


      } else if(element.hasClass('faq-bloc')){
        // console.log('part text only');

        elements = element.find('p, h3');

        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.pause();

        tl.staggerFromTo(
          elements,
          0.5,
          {
            alpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            alpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power3.easeOut
          },
          0.15,
          0.1
        );
        tl.play();
        scene.offset(-200);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);

      } else if(element.hasClass('promo-box')) {
        // console.log('part bloc');

        images = element.find('.image-container');
        btn = element.find('.is--cta-anim');

        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.pause();

        tl.call(function() {
          images.each(function(index) {
            var image = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              image.addClass('is-visible');
            }, index*100);
          });
        }, null, null, 0);

        tl.fromTo(
          btn,
          0.5,
          {
            alpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            alpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power3.easeOut
          },
          0.5+(images.length*0.1)
        );
        tl.play();
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);

      } else if(element.hasClass('bloc') || element.hasClass('influenceurs__group') || element.hasClass('journal__group')){
        // console.log('part bloc');

        images = element.find('.image-container');
        elements = element.find('p:not(.share), h1, h2, h3, .num a, button');
        btn = element.find('.is--cta-anim');

        var delayCall = 0;

        if (element.find($('.largest-selection--cat')).length) {
          elements = element.find('p, h1, h2, h3, .num a, .largest-selection--cat');
        } else if(element.find($('.slick-slider')).length) {
          elements = element.find('p, h1, h2, h3, .num a, .slick-slide');
          images = element.find('.image-container:not(.slick-slide), .image-container.slick-active');
        } else if(element.find($('.social')).length) {
          elements = element.find('p, h1, .e-parallax-container h1, .social ');
          if (element.hasClass('e-parallax-container')) {
            delayCall = 1;
          }
        }

        // Animation
        tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.pause();

        tl.call(function() {
          images.each(function(index) {
            var image = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
              image.addClass('is-visible');
            }, index*100);
          });
        }, null, this, delayCall);

        tl.staggerFromTo(
          elements,
          0.5,
          {
            alpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            alpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power1.easeOut
          },
          0.15,
          0.5
        );
        tl.fromTo(
          btn,
          0.5,
          {
            alpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            alpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power1.easeOut
          },
          0.5+(elements.length*0.1)
        );
        if (fireAnimation) {
          tl.play();
        } else {
          var play = setInterval(function(){
            // console.log(fireAnimation);
            if (fireAnimation) {
              clearInterval(play);
              tl.play();
            }
          }, 100);
        }
        scene.offset(-100);
        scene.setTween(tl);
        scene.addTo(controller);
      }

    });

    scrollAnimation = true;

  };

  /* =================================================================== */
  /**
   * Check isMobile or not .
   * @return  {bool}
   */
  function isMobile() {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 768)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  if(!isMobile() && !scrollAnimation ) {
    initScrollAnimations();
    initParallax();
    initParallaxVertical();
  }

  /* =================================================================== */
  // On load
  /* =================================================================== */
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    loaded = true;
    isLoaded();

    $('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function() {
      var $img = jQuery(this);
      var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
      var attributes = $img.prop("attributes");

      $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        $.each(attributes, function() {
          $svg.attr(this.name, this.value);
        });

        $img.replaceWith($svg);
      }, 'xml');
    });

  });

  /* =================================================================== */
  // MENU
  /* =================================================================== */


  function initMenuInter() {
    var top  = 0;
    var win = $(window);
    win.on('scroll', function () {
      $('.header-nav').toggleClass('menu-hidden',win.scrollTop()>top);
      top = win.scrollTop();
    })

  }

  function initMenuMobile() {
    var htmlbody = $('html,body');
    var arrow = $(".arrow-to-top");
    var toggle = $('.toggle');
    var menu = $('.menu-toggle');
    var ulMenu = $('.menu-mobile');
    var liMenu = $('.menu-mobile li');
    var aMenu = $('.a-item-mobile');

    // ir arriba
    arrow.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop:0
      },500);

      return false;
    });
    toggle.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $(this).toggleClass('opened');
      menu.toggleClass('dark-menu');
      ulMenu.toggleClass('menu-mobile-opened');
      liMenu.toggleClass('item-li-opened');
      aMenu.toggleClass('item-a-opened');
    });
  }


  // Load
  /* =================================================================== */
  function isLoaded() {
    $('.loading').removeClass('is--active');
    $('.header').removeClass('not--clickable');
    initMenuInter();
    initMenuMobile();
    setTimeout(function() {
      initMenuAnimation();
    }, speed/1.5);

  }
});
```

Comment: Podiras pegar el contenido de tus ficheros tsconfig.json y tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: Ahora mismo lo pongo! :)

Comment: Lo único raro que veo es la propiedad `"importHelpers"`, prueba a ponerla a false a ver. Si sigue fallando, cuelga el fichero js donde declaras esas funciones

Comment: Nada, sigue igual. Os dejo el js con las funciones

Comment: Estás usando JQuery en una aplicación con Angular 7?

Comment: ...si? estoy aprendiendo, no sé si es lo realmente correcto

Comment: No, no es la forma mas correcta, de hecho, es muy poco recomendable. Una de las bases de angular es dejar el DOM y sus elementos a Angular, y tu fichero modifica directamente el DOM. Te recomiendo empezar por el Tour https://angular.io/tutorial , lo que quieres hacer en tu fichero JQuery se puede conseguir con angular, pero siguendo las directrices de Angular. Como primera regla, deberías tener en cuenta que, por norma, no suele ser buena idea mezclar dos librerías de este tipo. Los eventos de jquery que usas tienen sus 'equivalencias' en angular, pero deberías hacerlo al 'estilo angular'

Answer (score 2):

Si esas funciones no tienen dependencias lo mas sencillo sería, en el fichero donde las tengas declaradas:

```js
    export function rearmScrollAnimations() {
       var pageloaded = $('.image-container');
       if (!pageloaded.hasClass('is-visible')){
           initScrollAnimations();
       }else{
           console.log('Todo funciona');
       }
    }
```

Luego, en el fichero donde lo quieras llamar, solo tienes que importar esa funcion:

```js
   import {rearmScrollAnimations} from '../..';
```

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error: Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (2:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. Tengo que poner en la primera línea el Export? Si es así me indica que la función que ejecuta esta función no está definida

Comment: Estas usando Angular 2+, verdad?

Comment: Angular 7, Sí! es un problema para este tipo de error?

Comment: No no, no es ningún problema. Solo por asegurarnos, entiendo que el `from` en el import lo has cambiado por el path relativo a tu fichero de funciones, no?

Comment: Sí, se me ha quedado tal que así: import {rearmScrollAnimations} from '../../../assets/js/prrrcl-app';
la función me la agarra, de hecho si el export lo pongo eso, en la primera línea del js, lo agarra sin problemas. El problema va que ahora me pide la otra función que está dentro de ésta última.